# Why my view HTML file with Thymeleaf doesn't display list of Objects in Spting application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, thymeleaf

I'm having trouble with displaying list of People when I pass it to the view adding it as a **modelAttribute**

Here is a short snippet of code related to the issue:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/people")
 public class PeopleController {

  private final PersonDAO personDAO;

 @Autowired
 public PeopleController(PersonDAO personDAO) {
     this.personDAO = personDAO;
 }

 @GetMapping()
 public String index(Model model){
     model.addAttribute("people", personDAO.index());
     return "people/index";
 }
}
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://thymeleaf.org/ ">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>All people</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div th:each="person : ${people}">
  <a th:href="@{/people/{id}(id =${person.getId()})}" th:text ="${person.getName() + ', ' + 
  person.getSurname()
  + ', ' + person.getAge() + ', ' + person.getUsername() + ', ' + person.getPassword()}">VALUE</a>
 </div>
 <br/>
 <hr/>
 <a href="/people/new">Create new person</a>
</body>
```

I could display full list of People , which I got from *personDAO.index()* just before returning my view *return"people/index"* , in console and everything works fine. So I suppose that list  **SELECT**  all objects properly and passing it to model.

That's what behind ***personDAO.index();*** method:

```
List<Person> people = session.createQuery("from People", Person.class ).list();
```

But the web page is empty. May be the problem is hidden inside my view file.
I would be thankful for helping me to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: When I made the same example using your `people/index` file, the list appears full, no problem. Do you get an error in "console" when your page is empty?

Comment: @ismlyldz no any error message as well as no any reference to /people/new in the end of the page. Just blank page

Comment: I posted the working version using the **same codes below**, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I created the `Person` model as in the example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String age;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Person() {
    }

    // getter/setter ..
}
```

2. I created a `PersonRepository` to get the people. You can check the **[Working with Spring Data Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories)** page for more.

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

3. I created `PeopleController`.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PeopleController {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    public PeopleController(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("people", personRepository.findAll());
        return "people/index";
    }
}
```

4. I have created `index.html` inside the `/resources/templates/people/` folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org/"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://thymeleaf.org/ ">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>All People</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:each="person : ${people}">
        <a th:href="@{/people/{id}(id =${person.getId()})}"
           th:text ="${person.getName() + ', ' + person.getSurname() + ', ' +
                       person.getAge() + ', ' + person.getUsername() + ', ' +
                       person.getPassword()}">VALUE</a>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <a href="/people/new">Create new person</a>
</body>
```

5. I added a few records to the `person table` as an example.

[image]

6. I think I have reached the result you want to see.

[image]

Comment: My code is almost the same , I have some weird thing, my getters are marked as never used but I suppose they should cause every object is  iterated in my view file. Any thoughts?

Comment: The questions I can think of may be a similar controller, library versions, html page may be different.